# How to extend with a new element the second xsd schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two xsd-s which I use to validate two types of xml. One xsd is extended from the first one, and the xml that I need to validate with this xsd can contain elements, attributes from the first xsd and from this extended xsd.

This is the part from my first xsd

```xml
<xs:complexType name="ModelType">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
          This is the root model type.
          It is a container for the elements, relationships, diagrams and organizations of the model.
      </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="NamedReferenceableType">
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:group ref="PropertiesGroup" />

        <xs:element name="metadata" type="MetadataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The "metadata" element is the optional meta-data for the model.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="elements" type="ElementsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The "elements" element is optional and is a container for all elements.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="relationships" type="RelationshipsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The "relationships" element is optional and is a container for all relationships.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="organizations" type="OrganizationsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The "organizations" element is optional and is a container for the tree nodes of the different structural organization of model elements and relationships.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="propertyDefinitions" type="PropertyDefinitionsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <!--<xs:element name="exporttype" type="xs:string" />-->

      </xs:sequence>

      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="optional">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Specifies the version of the model.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I need that my second `xsd` to contain an element named `exporttype`, which should be a child of the `ModelType` from my first `xsd`. The xml that I need to validate with this first `xsd` should not contain this `exporttype` element, but the second xml will contain the `exporttype` element. I need to validate this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" identifier="id-5f48f73ea7067b68f0dbf81f" xmlns="http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/">
  <name xml:lang="EN"></name>
  <exporttype>test</exporttype>
  <views>
    <diagrams>
      <view identifier="id-3710ccd2-e603-4002-bea5-2033788047b9">
        <name xml:lang="EN">shapes</name>
        <node xmlns:q1="" xsi:type="q1:Shape" identifier="id-a969ed9d-a0d6-47cb-8d8b-045cf32adb61" x="290" y="30" w="1" h="1" nameinternal="" shapeId="5dad5bcd4527ecc5c8c49256" angle="0" isgroup="False" alignment="" textalign="0" size="72 72">
          <label xml:lang="EN" />
          <style>
            <fillColor r="209" g="210" b="212" />
            <font name="Lato" size="13">
              <color r="0" g="0" b="0" />
            </font>
          </style>
        </node>
        <node xmlns:q2=" xsi:type=" q2:Shape" identifier=" id-5397a6f6-b1bf-428d-af84-8ad69468951d" x=" 10" y=" 32" w=" 1" h=" 1" nameinternal=" 5dad54fd0c0ba639c4a5b50c" angle=" 0" isgroup=" False" alignment=" 0" size=" 72 87,171">
          <label xml:lang=" EN" />
          <style>
            <fillColor r=" 209" g=" 210" b=" 212" />
            <font name=" Lato" size=" 13">
              <color r=" 0" g=" 0" b=" 0" />
            </font>
          </style>
        </node>
      </view>
    </diagrams>
  </views>
</model>
```

I've tried something like this to put in the second xsd

```
   <xs:element name="exporttype" type="xs:string"/>
```

for this I got that the exportype is not the child of the modeltype

I've also tried something like this:

```
 <xs:complexType name="barType">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="archimate:ModelType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="exporttype" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a choice:

a) Add the extra element as an optional element within the original schema
This will allow the export tag always, but it will not be mandatory.

b) Create a separate element declaration 'ModelTypeExtended' which contains the extra tag. Use ModelType as your root tag when you want the original content. Use ModelTypeExtended when you want to include the new tag.

c) Create a new complex type 'barType' which extends the original complex type. When you want to validate against the extended version, use `<Model xsi:type="barType" ...`  to ensure that the XSD validator picks the extended version of the type.

d) Carefully control which XSD your application uses (not recommended)

You cannot use the same tag name and have different validation rules unless you choose option d), but hardly anybody does that.